# Dynamically load images from folder for slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic

my task is to create a webpage containing a slideshow, dynamically getting the displayed images from a folder.
For the slideshow I used this "tutorial": https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp.
I did some modifications based on my needs - works like a charm.
The only open task is the part with the dynamic loading of the images. I need every image in a folder to be added to the body, so my js includes the image to the slideshow. Additionally, for every image I want to add another "bullet point", which indicates the current position.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Slideshow</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!--Linking CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>

</head>
<body>

<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="images/rick.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>
      
<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="images/rick2.png" style="width:100%">
</div>
      
<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="images/rick3.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="images/rick4.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="images/rick6.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

</div>


<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>

<!--Linking JS-->
<script src="script.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {
  overflow: hidden; /* hiding scrollbars */
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

img {vertical-align: middle;}


.mySlides {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px; /* distance between dots */
  background-color: #bbb; /* maybe change to RS */
  display: inline-block; /* inline-block */
  position: relative; top:-70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
 
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
let slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

//Function to make automatic slideshow
function showSlides() {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 20000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

The goal is to have a running webpage with the slideshow, so when a person adds a new image to the images folder, I do not have to add another

```
<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="images/image.xy" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

and another

```
<span class="dot"></span>
```

into the
`<div style="text-align:center"> </div>`

Any help to achieve this is highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Seekign libraries or tools is out of the scope for SO. Besides that, there is no easy solution to it. The easiest way is using a database that keeps idnexing pictures that are uploaded by the user and using the database to load the images. I would prefer a server-sided language such as PHp for this task.

Comment: @tacoshy Hey, danke für deine Nachricht, ist es möglich, mit dir privat zu schreiben? Was meinst du in dem Fall mit "SO"? Bin ein relativer Neuling was Webprogrammierung angeht und schustere mir hier irgendwas zusammen.